# generic type alias, which are incompatible to each other

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, generic-programming, type-alias

I am trying to construct some kind of "generic type alias", meaning I want to define a type as `int` for example, but with a generic type argument which then makes it incompatible with instances of other types.

I tried doing this with alias templates:

```
template <typename T>
using NumberWithSemantics = int;
```

But the problem with this is that all instantiations, no matter the type `T`, are considered equal, for example:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

NumberWithSemantics<A> getThing() {
    return 14;
}

int processDifferentThing(NumberWithSemantics<B> b) {
    return b * 3;
}

int main() {
    auto a = getThing();
    return processDifferentThing(a); // unfortunately compiles just fine
}
```

Is there a way to define some kind of generic type alias that disallows mixing different template instantiations?

Comment: I would recommend reading the [strong types series](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/05/named-constructors/) on Fluent C++. The part you're most interested is probably [the second article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/).

Comment: Thanks, following that advice the most minimal solution for me was to replace `using NumberWithSemantics = int;` with `struct NumberWithSemantics { int value; }`

Comment: If anyone can explain why exactly template structs work and template aliases don't, I'd have an answer to accept :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ has type aliasing, but it is only *weak* type aliasing. When you say

```
typedef int MyType;
```

or

```
using MyType = int;
```

you tell the compiler, “whenever you see `MyType`, pretend you had just seen `int` instead”. There is then *no difference at all* between `MyType i` and `int i`; both create a variable named `i` of type `int`. Making the `using` declaration a template doesn’t help; all of the types equivalently mean `int`.

What you want to do is create an actual new type. To do this, you need to declare it with `struct` or `class`, not just `using`. Even if they look the same, the type system will treat each new type created this way as a separate type; by extension, if you make a template `struct`, each instantiation will be a new type.

Therefore, the minimum potential solution would be:

```
template <typename T>
struct NumberWithSemantics { int i; };
```

Then you can use `NumberWithSemantics<A>` and `NumberWithSemantics<B>` as different types. However, you will need to keep saying `.i` to get the actual value out, which can make your code harder to read. There are various possible ways to get around that, for which I recommend reading [this part](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/23/strong-types-inheriting-functionalities-from-underlying/) of the Strong Types series on Fluent C++.